# Ambiguous between the following methods or properties in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, html-helper, stimulsoft

I use Stimulsoft and when I want to generate report,I see this error:

```
 CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcBaseHelper.Stimulsoft(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' and 'Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcBaseHelper.Stimulsoft(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'
```

and my .cshtml file:

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "GetCardReportS";
}
<head>
   @Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcViewerScripts();
</head>

@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
    ActionViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent",
    ActionPrintReport = "PrintReport",
    ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
    ActionInteraction = "Interaction"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *explicitly* specify the fully-qualified name of the Property which you would like to use.

There are probably more than one Property with *same name* within your references - Do you reference to two different versions of the same Library (`Stimulsoft`)?

**UPDATE:**

It's most likely that you are using two different versions of the ***`Stimulsoft`*** library.
Using the **Modules** window, you'll be able to investigate it properly:

At run-time\debugging mode: Debug-> Windows -> Modules.

Comment: I have 1 reference of Stimulsoft DLL

Comment: @SaeedPy How did you check your current references?

Comment: In my references in project

Comment: It is not completely represent all of your references.

Comment: Check the modules window while debugging: Debug-> Windows -> Modules

Answer (score 1):

Those two types seem to be the same, so they must be loaded from different assemblies. Make sure that you only load one version of the Stimulsoft assembly or assemblies. The "modules" window of Visual Studio displays the list of assemblies. It is possible that you have multiple references in the web.config for example.

Comment: I check my web.config,but I do not have any multiple references.

Comment: Check the modules window while debugging.